# A motor with high holding torque?

Tags: motor

Is there a motor which has regular torque, but extremely high holding torque? I mean, the motor probably holds by some mechanical lock rather than by the torque generated by the magnetic field. Is there some such motor, either linear or regular?

Comment: Do you need the regular speed of that motor to be fast (thousands of RPM)? If not, you can put reduction gearing on normal DC motor. This provides very high holding torque, especially if you lock the motor electrically.

Comment: how about a disc brake?

Answer (score 4):

A [worm gear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worm_drive) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

What you seem to be describing is a motor with a friction brake. The usual type of brake used is a spring-set brake. A spring applies the brake and a electric solenoid releases the brake by compressing the spring. That way, power is not required for the brake to hold. AC motors are readily available with a spring set brake mounted on one end.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your definition of holding.

A stepper motor will have a high holding torque within plus minus half the pole angle.

If it's a servo motor with positional feedback and proper controls you can also lock a motor "around" one spot with a lot of torque.

If you need it rock solid in both directions, or need it to hold when the lights go out, a worm gear or mechanical lock / brake will be required.

Answer (score 2):

One common type for industrial purposes is referred to as a "Brake Motor" or "Conical Brake Motor".

This type of motor is arranged such that the magnetic forces that create the motor rotation also cause the armature to move laterally such that when the motor is unpowered a spring forces the armature into its resting position and engages a brake. It can therefore slow-down the load and lock it in place.

Comment: I have seen these motors when I was very young . +1